# IIS configuration blocks HttpClient requests

Tags: c#, iis, dotnet-httpclient, windows-server-2016, iis-10

We have a strange Problem with one of our customer enviroments.
Basicly we want to call a simple api from microsoft to get a json result.

Nothing magic at all.
(This is just a test api to call any endpoint we want)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TestJsonEndpoint")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestJsonEndpoint(string endpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(endpoint)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return Ok(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var o = new { response.StatusCode, content };

            return Ok(o);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Problem now is that on our TestSystems, even local Systems the programm works fine and any endpoint can be reached.

On our customer enviroment we get this response from each endpoint httpclient call:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Error sending the request.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
  "StackTrace": "   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   ",
  "InnerException": {
                    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The connection to the remote server cannot be established .",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
    "StackTrace": "   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)",
    "InnerException": {
                        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "A connection attempt failed because the remote station did not react correctly after a certain period of time, or the connection established was faulty because the connected host did not react 80.228.37.106:443 ",
      "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
      "StackTrace": "   bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   bei System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)"
    }
```

We checked the IIS configuration for almost 10000 times, checked even the Features that are installed on the server for the IIS, asp.net framework and so on but everything seems normal.
Basicly nothing is configured on the IIS. Even the Firewall on the server is deactivated. No proxy is set.

Why it seems the problem is the IIS? When we browse the endpoint in the browser it works fine! I created also a simple consoleapplication with the exact same httpclient call and even this is working fine...

It is an Windows Server 2016
IIS Version 10

Has somebody an idea what to do?

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? Either of them has built-in network tracing which can help you identify the cause.

Comment: Could you please have a try with put the `endpoint` in string type in `client.GetAsync(endpoint)` instead of use `new Uri()`.

Comment: Thanks for the adivces. We will test both comments it in the start of the new week. Unfortenatly we have no access to the server today. The tracing looks promising. Hopefully there will be a better logging available as the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Is there any update about this post ? And could you please also check if there is any limits in your customer's network ?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. We tested allot of things also with the build in network tracing. But the errormessages was the same and all other informations in the log where not meaningfull to find a solution. We transfered the problem to the customers enviroment and the Administration is looking at some limitations at their enviroment currently. But there are no new infos currently available...

Comment: If still can't find the cause of the problem, maybe you can create a support ticket and ask microsoft engineer for help on this [page](https://support.microsoft.com/).